# Parallel reality in The Secrets of Dumbledore

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

There are several cases in the movie where characters seem to exist in some kind of other reality. Can it be explained by in-universe magic? Or is it just a metaphorical way of showing the importance of the moment for the viewer?

The cases are:

> The duel between Dumbledore and Credence

> The duel between Dumbledore and Drindelwald

Answer (score 1):

#### In the first case: The duel took place in an illusion of Berlin that Dumbledore created.

The official companion book “The Secrets of Dumbledore: Movie Magic explains that Dumbledore’s duel with Credence takes place in a fake “mirror world” version of Berlin that Dumbledore created.

[image]

It was not a separate dimension, but an illusion within the same dimension.

#### In the second case: It was most likely just to slow the action down for the viewers.

When Dumbledore fought Grindelwald, they were most likely not in an alternate dimension or an illusion - it was likely just shown in a way that the viewers could more easily see what was happening.

Comment: When Dumbledore fought Grindelwald, no one in the real world seemed to know what the two were doing or even see their duel. Some of their spells hit a barrier, which represents the dimensions of the elevated part of the Eyrie. If there wasn't an alternate dimension, then the wizards below, like Theseus, Newt, Liu Tao, Vicência Santos, Vinda Rosier, Carrow, Queenie, Bunty, the supporters of the Candidates for the Supreme Mugwump would've hidden for cover/protection. Also, when Dumbledore and Grindelwald returned, no one seemed to pay attention to them, as they were focused on the election.